# JSON Feed for Twitter for profile image URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I am trying to figure out the way to download an image file for Twitter JSON URL asynchronously like LazyTableImages. 
JSON File looks like :

```
{
"completed_in": 0.132,
"max_id": 99177223541628930,
"max_id_str": "99177223541628928",
"next_page": "?page=2&max_id=99177223541628928&q=mobile&rpp=1",
"page": 1,
"query": "mobile",
"refresh_url": "?since_id=99177223541628928&q=mobile",
"results": [
    {
        "created_at": "Thu, 04 Aug 2011 17:57:47 +0000",
        "from_user": "twhp_Bastary",
        "from_user_id": 235609046,
        "from_user_id_str": "235609046",
        "geo": {
            "coordinates": [
                -2.6766,
                118.8793
            ],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "id": 99177223541628930,
        "id_str": "99177223541628928",
        "iso_language_code": "en",
        "metadata": {
            "result_type": "recent"
        },
        "profile_image_url": "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1431110298/315762105_normal.jpg",
        "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://ubersocial.com&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;ÜberSocial for BlackBerry&lt;/a&gt;",
        "text": "RT @DamnItsTrue: Good friends are priceless! #DamnItsTrue http://myloc.me/m9Kot",
        "to_user_id": null,
        "to_user_id_str": null
    }
],
"results_per_page": 1,
"since_id": 0,
"since_id_str": "0"
```

}

The key profile_image_URL needs to be load the images asynchronously while scrolling the tableview such that it does not kill client experience of scrolling.
Code used to load JSON is using NSDictionary with each tags as key.

```
    NSDictionary *tweets = [twitter objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

cell.textLabel.text = [tweets objectForKey:@"text"];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

NSString *URL = [tweets objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tweets objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]];
NSData *Tweetdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:Tweetdata];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the ImageLoadingOperation class from the Stanford CS193P sample code.

Google will find various project using it.

If you find a more up to date way, maybe using block, please post any results.

It would be good to know the most efficient way of doing this with the latest SDK.

edit - links

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-winter is the page

this project uses a threaded method to download photo's from flickr. This is what I used:
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/11-ThreadedFlickrTableView.zip

The ImageLoadingOperation is a subclass of NSOperation. When the tableview cell requests a new image, it adds the URL to the queue and is downloaded to a local NSDictionary on a background thread. When its downloaded its uses performSelectorOnMainThread to reload the tableview on the main thread which grabs the image form the dictionary.

Hope it helps.

Comment: where did you find that reference I mean do you have a URL >

Comment: Thanks. Will try the logic !!